How can I copy x bytes from the start of the file and append them to the end of the file to increase the file by x bytes?
here are my parameters:
1: I accept one command line as an argument - an integer positive number x.
If an invalid number of arguments is given, the program must end with error code 115
2: I copied the fragment of the file text1.txt from the beginning of the file to x byte to the end of the same file, i.e. the file must increase by X byte
3: If X is greater than the file size, the program must copy only as much data as there is in the original file and write them from the specified position X
4: the program must output the file text1.txt with the i-node number and the number of copied bytes
the general idea is that if my text1.txt file is this:
1/2+23asd
and i choose to copy 3 bytes, text1.txt file should look like this after launching the program:
1/2+23asd1/2
here is my try below, but i cant seem to get it to work: after launching and before, text1.txt stays the same
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void copy_file_fragment(int x) {
    
    FILE *file = fopen("text1.txt", "r+b");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    long file_size = ftell(file);

    
    long copy_position = (x < file_size) ? x : file_size;

   
    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    size_t bytes_read;

   
    fseek(file, copy_position, SEEK_SET);

    bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, file_size - copy_position, file);

    
    fseek(file, copy_position, SEEK_SET);

   
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, file);

    
    fclose(file);

    
    struct stat st;
    if (stat("text1.txt", &st) == -1) {
        perror("Error getting file information");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Inode Number: %ld\n", st.st_ino);
    printf("Copied Byte Number: %zu\n", bytes_read);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <x>\n", argv[0]);
        return 115;
    }

 
    int x = atoi(argv[1]);

    
    copy_file_fragment(x);

    return 0;
}


You seek to the same location for reading and writing , so no wonder it stays the same

Position the file pointer to the start of the file, read x bytes, reposition the file pointer back to the start of the file, write x bytes. Hmmm... I see an issue there.

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); and long file_size = ftell(file); to get the size of a file is fundamentally broken in a lot of ways.  long on Windows is only 32 bits, for example.  See How do you determine the size of a file in C?

Please clarify your #3. Posit: the file contains 20 characters, and X is 50. Two options: 1) double the size of the file (20+20=40), or 2) grab all available (20), pad to offset 50 and there write out the 20. (20 + (50) = 70). Please edit the question to make your objective clear.

If this is a practical matter, the shell utilities head, >> (append), cat, and stat can do what you want. The following will append 5 bytes from the top of test.txt to the end, print test.txt, and its inode.
head -c5 test.txt >> test.txt
cat test.txt
stat --format '%i' test.txt


The problem is you're reading from and writing to the same spot. The result is no change.
    // Reading X bytes from copy_position.
    fseek(file, copy_position, SEEK_SET);
    bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, file_size - copy_position, file);

    // Writing X bytes to copy_position.
    fseek(file, copy_position, SEEK_SET);   
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, file);

To do this manually, it's simpler than you're making it.

Open the file for r+
Read X bytes.
Seek to the end.
Write X bytes.

    FILE *file = fopen(Filename, "r+b");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    size_t bytes_read = fread(buffer, 1, x, file);

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, file);

    fclose(file);

Additional notes:

Because you're using a fixed buffer, check that x is not greater than your buffer.
Every file operation should be checked, but definitely do fseek else you'll overwrite the file.


You don't need to know the size of the file - you can just open the file in append mode.  And using POSIX file-descriptor-based open(), etc. can be much simpler:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>


ssize_t copy_file_fragment( const char *filename, size_t fragmentSize )
{
    // open in append mode because that's what we're doing
    int fd = open( filename, O_RDWR | O_APPEND );
    if ( fd < 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "open( %s ) failed, errno %d\n", filename, errno );
        return( -1 );
    }

    // fragment can be large, don't use stack for it
    char *buf = malloc( fragmentSize );
    if ( NULL == buf )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "malloc( %zu ) failed, errno %d\n", fragmentSize , errno );
        close( fd );
        return( -1 );
    }

    // read from start of file
    ssize_t bytesRead = pread( fd, buf, fragmentSize, 0 );
    if ( bytesRead < 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "pread( %s ) failed, errno %d\n", filename, errno );
        free( buf );
        close( fd );
        return( -1 );
    }

    // file opened with O_APPEND, so this will go at the end, no seek needed
    ssize_t bytesWritten = write( fd, buf, bytesRead );
    if ( bytesWritten < 0 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "write( %s ) failed, errno %d\n", filename, errno );
    }

    free( buf );
    close ( fd );

    return( bytesWritten );
}

If the file size is smaller than fragmentSize, the full contents of the file will be duplicated.  That may or may not be what you want to do.
Without error checking, to make what the code does much more apparent:
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

ssize_t copy_file_fragment( const char *filename, size_t fragmentSize )
{
    int fd = open( filename, O_RDWR | O_APPEND );

    char *buf = malloc( fragmentSize );

    ssize_t bytesRead = pread( fd, buf, fragmentSize, 0 );

    ssize_t bytesWritten = write( fd, buf, bytesRead );

    free( buf );
    close ( fd );

    return( bytesWritten );
}

